# XSLT tokenize a string that's distributed across child elements

Tags: xslt, text, xslt-2.0, children, tokenize

I have the feeling there's an obvious solution out there, but I can't think of it. Using XSLT 2.0 I want to tokenize a string that's distributed across child elements, so it's something like

```
<line>
    <font style="big">
        <text color="blue">wha</text>
    </font>
    <font style="small">
        <text color="red">t is o</text>
    </font>
    <font style="small">
        <text color="blue">n </text>
    </font>
    <font style="small">
        <text color="blue">his </text>
    </font>
    <font style="small">
        <text color="blue">mind.</text>
    </font>
</line>
```

I would like to tokenize the value of the string, i.e., split the string on blanks and punctuation marks, but still keep each segment in its tree structure. So what I want to get:

```
<line>
    <token>
        <font style="big">
            <text color="blue">wha</text>
        </font>
        <font style="small">
            <text color="red">t</text>
        </font>
    </token>
    <token>
        <font style="small">
            <text color="red">is</text>
        </font>
    </token>
    <token>
        <font style="small">
            <text color="red">o</text>
        </font>
        <font style="small">
            <text color="blue">n</text>
        </font>
    </token>
  <token>
      <font style="small">
          <text color="blue">his</text>
      </font>
  </token>
  <token>
    <font style="small">
        <text color="blue">mind</text>
    </font>
  </token>
  <token>
    <font style="small">
      <text color="blue">.</text>
    </font>
  </token
</line>
```

I.E., move every word and punctuation mark into a seperate token element. Now, with just a string, that's easy, and I could use one of analyze-string or matches(), but I can't find an elegant and robust solution for this task.

I'll be thrilled to hear your ideas, 
Ruprecht

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does half the job, tokenising the strings, it doesn't add your `<token>` markup as if I understand it correctly that requires dictionary lookup to recognise words. It produces

```
<line>
   <font style="big">
      <text color="blue">wha</text>
   </font>
   <font style="small">
      <text color="red">t</text>
   </font>
   <font style="small">
      <text color="red">is</text>
   </font>
   <font style="small">
      <text color="red">o</text>
   </font>
   <font style="small">
      <text color="blue">n</text>
   </font>
   <font style="small">
      <text color="blue">his</text>
   </font>
   <font style="small">
      <text color="blue">mind.</text>
   </font>
</line>
```

stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
<xsl:output indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="*">
 <xsl:copy>
  <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
  <xsl:apply-templates/>
 </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="font">
 <xsl:variable name="fa" select="@*"/>
 <xsl:for-each select="text">
  <xsl:variable name="ta" select="@*"/>
  <xsl:for-each select="text()/tokenize(.,'\s+')[.]">
   <font>
    <xsl:copy-of select="$fa"/>
    <text>
     <xsl:copy-of select="$ta"/>
     <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </text>
   </font>
  </xsl:for-each>
 </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

OK updated after clarification in comments, it now generates

```
<line>
   <token>
      <font style="big">
         <text color="blue">wha</text>
      </font>
      <font style="small">
         <text color="red">t</text>
      </font>
   </token>
   <token>
      <font style="small">
         <text color="red">is</text>
      </font>
   </token>
   <token>
      <font style="small">
         <text color="red">o</text>
      </font>
      <font style="small">
         <text color="blue">n</text>
      </font>
   </token>
   <token>
      <font style="small">
         <text color="blue">his</text>
      </font>
   </token>
   <token>
      <font style="small">
         <text color="blue">mind</text>
      </font>
   </token>
   <token>
      <font style="small">
         <text color="blue">.</text>
      </font>
   </token>
</line>
```

xslt:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
 <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
   <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="*[font]">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
   <xsl:variable name="p1">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
   </xsl:variable>
   <xsl:for-each-group  select="$p1/*" group-starting-with="tok">
    <token>
     <xsl:copy-of select="current-group() except self::tok"/>
    </token>
   </xsl:for-each-group>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="font">
  <xsl:variable name="fa" select="@*"/>
  <xsl:for-each select="text">
   <xsl:variable name="ta" select="@*"/>
   <xsl:if test="position()=1 and matches(.,'^\s')"><tok/></xsl:if>
   <xsl:for-each select="text()/tokenize(.,'\s+')[.]">
    <xsl:if test="position()!=1"><tok/></xsl:if>
    <xsl:analyze-string regex="[.,;?]" select=".">
     <xsl:matching-substring>
      <tok/>
      <font>
       <xsl:copy-of select="$fa"/>
       <text>
    <xsl:copy-of select="$ta"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
       </text>
      </font>
     </xsl:matching-substring>
     <xsl:non-matching-substring>
      <font>
       <xsl:copy-of select="$fa"/>
       <text>
    <xsl:copy-of select="$ta"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
       </text>
      </font>
     </xsl:non-matching-substring>
    </xsl:analyze-string>
   </xsl:for-each>
   <xsl:if test="position()=last() and matches(.,'\s$')"><tok/></xsl:if>
  </xsl:for-each>
 </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks! I should have been clearer on this: no dictionary is necessary, the idea is to splits the string on blanks and punctuation marks. But I see: perhaps the easiest way is to reorganize this tree into tokens.

Comment: Answer updated to tokenize according to white space and punctuation

Comment: thanks for this answer. this problems occurs when parsing open office text (and many other formats) and one needs to (a) tokenize the text and (b) retain the formatting. in an additional step, i simplify the formating to remove redundant tags.